# Import image in xlsx file

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, xlsx, openpyxl

(Sorry for my english)
I want to insert a lot of images in xlsx. Images are QR codes. The first, I created QR code from one document, then I saved a lot of images in list and then I  tried insert this is images in xlsx file. Image must locate on 5,36,67,98,129,160,191 etc row. I inserted this,(I did formula 5+i*30+i) BUT each IMAGEs slide on some millimeters and after 5 image(for example), image locates on 100 row, INSTEAD 98...
How insert image exactly???

```
import qrcode
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing import Image
a1=[]
b1=[]
D=5
j=0
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:/python/python program/qr code/тсж14.xlsx')#запись информации которую нужно преобразовать в qr коды
sheet = wb['list1']
for i in range(617):
    i=i+15
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value!=None or sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value!=None:
        j=j+1
        a1.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value)#
j=0
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:/python/python program/qr code/qr.xlsx')#запись информации которую нужно преобразовать в qr коды

for i in range(200):#преобразование в QR код и запись в excel
    ws = wb.active
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=3,
        border=0,
    )
    qr.add_data(a1[i])
    qr.make(fit=True)
    print(a1[i])
    img = qr.make_image()
    img.save("C:/python/python program/qr code/11.png")#преобразование в QR код
    img = Image('C:/python/python program/qr code/11.png')
    D=5+i*30+i#запись в excel
    print(D)
    img.anchor(ws.cell(row=D, column=1))
    ws.add_image(img)#запись в excel

wb.save('C:/python/python program/qr code/qr.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please update the version of openpyxl you're using.

Comment: "Please update the version of openpyxl you're using." thanks a lot, it helped me. Really man, you are genius))

Comment: How did this help you? Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @JamesAMohler Not enough. The solution is located inside Excel. You should change setting in format image -- (right button on mouse)Format Image --> Setting -->  move and change object with cell (I don't know how it exactly call in English Excel)